# How to subtract two columns of different lengths from two tables?

Tags: r

I have two data frames like this:

| sample | data1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 2 | 250 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 3 | 240 |
| 4 | 180 |
| 5 | 190 |
| ... | .. |
| n | 200 |

| sample | data2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 |
| 2 | 230 |
| 3 | 260 |
| 4 | 200 |
| ... | .. |
| n | 200 |

I want data1 to be subtracted from data1 according to the sample. That is, 1: 300-150, 200-150; 2: 150-230, 300-230...

Comment: You'll need to join your data together first on the `sample` columns. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right for how to do this 'inner join'. Once you have `data2` brought across from the second table, you can then do the subtraction on the same length columns.

Comment: `transform(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), subs = data1 - data2)`

Comment: 'library(plyr)

df1 = join(df1, df2,
     type = "inner")'  @thelatemail hi I check the link and find this code works for me! many thanks!

Comment: @onyambu hi I tried the code you write but it's failed since the length is different. but inner join the table is work for me. thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: the code works look at the solution below. Merge and inner join are exactly the same, you can also use `mutate` instead of transform

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), subs = data1 - data2)
   sample data1 data2 subs
1       1   200   150   50
2       1   300   150  150
3       2   150   230  -80
4       2   300   230   70
5       2   250   230   20
6       3   200   260  -60
7       3   240   260  -20
8       4   180   200  -20
9       5   190    NA   NA
10      n   200   200    0
```

---

```
df1 <- structure(list(sample = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "5", "n"), data1 = c(300L, 200L, 150L, 300L, 250L, 200L, 
240L, 180L, 190L, 200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df2 <- structure(list(sample = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "n"), data2 = c(150L, 
230L, 260L, 200L, 200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```